# Why is this form of block synchronizing faster than the other?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

So, I just finished this assignment about synchronization, and I'm curious about the results I got, as I don't quite understand why one form is faster than the other.

There's an account class, defined as follows:

```
public class Account {

    /*
     * ------------
     * Data members
     * ------------
     */

    /**
     * Attribute presents an account number
     */

    private int acc;
    /**
     * Attribute that presents an customer name
     */
    private String name;
    /**
     * Attribute that presents an account balance
     */
    private double balance;

    /*
     * ------------
     * Constructors
     * ------------
     */

    /**
     * Assigns account number, name and balance.
     *
     * @param acc A unique integer that represents account number
     * @param name A string indicating human-readable customer's name
     * @param balance A double indicating account balance
     */

    public Account(int acc, String name, double balance) {
        super();
        this.acc = acc;
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;
    }


    @Override
    /**
     * equals method works as == operator 
     * it checks if two accounts are identical
     */
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Account other = (Account) obj;
        if (acc != other.acc)
            return false;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(balance) != Double
                .doubleToLongBits(other.balance))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (acc!=other.acc)return false;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Accessor for account no
     * @return account no
     */
    public int getAcc() {
        return acc;
    }

    /**
     * Mutator for account no 
     * @param acc A unique int for acoount number
     */
    public void setAcc(int acc) {
        this.acc = acc;
    }

    /**
     * Accessor for a customer's name
     * @return a customer's name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Mutator for a customer name
     * @param name A string that represents a customer name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Accessor for account balance
     * @return an account balance
     */
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    /**
     * Mutator for account balance
     * @param balance A double that represents an account balance
     */
    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    /**
     * A method to print this account 
     */
    public String toString(){
        return "Account: "+acc+" \tName: "+name+" \tBalance:\t"+balance;
    }

    /**
     * A method that allows a customer to deposit money into this account
     * @param amount A double that represents a deposit amount
     */
    public void debosit(double amount){

        // Waste some time doing fake computations
        // do not remove or modify any of the following 3 statements
        double k = 999999999;
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            k = k / 2;
            balance = balance + amount;
        // Waste some time doing fake computations
        // do not remove or modify any of the following 3 statements
        k = 999999999;
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            k = k / 2;

    }

    /**
     * A method that allows a customer to withdraw money from this account
     * @param amount A double that represents a withdrawal amount
     */
    public void withdraw(double amount){

        // Waste some time doing fake computations
        // do not remove or modify any of the following 3 statements

        double k = 999999999;
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            k = k / 2;
            balance = balance - amount;
        // Waste some time doing fake computations
        // do not remove or modify any of the following 3 statements
        k = 999999999;
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            k = k / 2;
    }


}

public void debosit(double amount){

        // Waste some time doing fake computations
        // do not remove or modify any of the following 3 statements
        double k = 999999999;
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            k = k / 2;
            balance = balance + amount;
        // Waste some time doing fake computations
        // do not remove or modify any of the following 3 statements
        k = 999999999;
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            k = k / 2;

    }

    /**
     * A method that allows a customer to withdraw money from this account
     * @param amount A double that represents a withdrawal amount
     */
    public void withdraw(double amount){

        // Waste some time doing fake computations
        // do not remove or modify any of the following 3 statements

        double k = 999999999;
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            k = k / 2;
            balance = balance - amount;
        // Waste some time doing fake computations
        // do not remove or modify any of the following 3 statements
        k = 999999999;
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            k = k / 2;
    }
```

The depositor class looks like this:

```
public class Depositor extends Thread {
    private Account account ;
    public Depositor(Account account){
        this.account = account;
    }


    public void run(){
        synchronized(account){
        for (int i=0;i<10000000;i++)
        {
            account.debosit(10);
            }
        /*          
        try {
                sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/
        }

    }

}
```

And the withdrawer class, is similar to deposit, just running the withdraw method instead of the deposit one.

The class with the main method is as follows:

```
public class AccountManager {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Account [] account = new Account[10];
        Depositor [] deposit = new Depositor[10];
        Withdrawer [] withdraw = new Withdrawer[10];

        // The birth of  10 accounts
        account[0] = new Account(1234,"Mike",1000);
        account[1] = new Account(2345,"Adam",2000);
        account[2] = new Account(3456,"Linda",3000);
        account[3] = new Account(4567,"John",4000);
        account[4] = new Account(5678,"Rami",5000);
        account[5] = new Account(6789,"Lee",6000);
        account[6] = new Account(7890,"Tom",7000);
        account[7] = new Account(8901,"Lisa",8000);
        account[8] = new Account(9012,"Sam",9000);
        account[9] = new Account(4321,"Ted",10000);

        // The birth of 10 depositors 
        deposit[0] = new Depositor(account[0]);
        deposit[1] = new Depositor(account[1]);
        deposit[2] = new Depositor(account[2]);
        deposit[3] = new Depositor(account[3]);
        deposit[4] = new Depositor(account[4]);
        deposit[5] = new Depositor(account[5]);
        deposit[6] = new Depositor(account[6]);
        deposit[7] = new Depositor(account[7]);
        deposit[8] = new Depositor(account[8]);
        deposit[9] = new Depositor(account[9]);

        // The birth of  10 withdraws 
        withdraw[0] = new Withdrawer(account[0]);
        withdraw[1] = new Withdrawer(account[1]);
        withdraw[2] = new Withdrawer(account[2]);
        withdraw[3] = new Withdrawer(account[3]);
        withdraw[4] = new Withdrawer(account[4]);
        withdraw[5] = new Withdrawer(account[5]);
        withdraw[6] = new Withdrawer(account[6]);
        withdraw[7] = new Withdrawer(account[7]);
        withdraw[8] = new Withdrawer(account[8]);
        withdraw[9] = new Withdrawer(account[9]);

        System.out.println("Print initial account balances");
        // Print initial account balances
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            System.out.println(account[i]);

        // Get start time in milliseconds 
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

        System.out.println("Depositor and Withdrawal threads have been created");
        /*
         * Interleave all threads
         */
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            deposit[i].start();
            withdraw[i].start();
        }


        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            try {
                deposit[i].join();
                withdraw[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // Get elapsed time in milliseconds 
        long elapsedTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()-start; 

        System.out.println("Print final account balances after all the child thread terminated...");
        // Print final account balances after all the child thread terminated...    
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            System.out.println(account[i]);
        // Get elapsed time in seconds 
        float elapsedTimeSec = elapsedTimeMillis/1000F;

        System.out.println("Elapsed time in milliseconds "+elapsedTimeMillis);
        System.out.println("Elapsed time in seconds is "+elapsedTimeSec);

        //  Get elapsed time in minutes 
        float elapsedTimeMin = elapsedTimeMillis/(60*1000F); 
        // Get elapsed time in hours 
        float elapsedTimeHour = elapsedTimeMillis/(60*60*1000F); 
        // Get elapsed time in days 
        float elapsedTimeDay = elapsedTimeMillis/(24*60*60*1000F); 

    }

}
```

Sorry, lots of code, but finally my question:

If I use block synchronization, I can put it directly in the account class, as follows:

```
public void withdraw(double amount){

        // Waste some time doing fake computations
        // do not remove or modify any of the following 3 statements

        double k = 999999999;
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            k = k / 2;
            synchronized(this)
                balance = balance - amount;
        // Waste some time doing fake computations
        // do not remove or modify any of the following 3 statements
        k = 999999999;
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            k = k / 2;
    }
```

This solution, when done on both, takes 1 second total to run. However, if I move the synchronization to the withdrawer and depositor classes, it looks like this:

```
public void run(){

        // Withdraw 10 CAD into instance variable account
        for (int i=0;i<10000000;i++)
        {
            synchronized(account)
                account.withdraw(10);

        }
    }
```

And this takes about 1/10th the time to run.

Why is this? Shouldn't they take the same amount of time?

Answer (score 1):

Locking has an overhead.  If you lock 100 times more, it should have 100 more locking overhead.

The reason you don't see a 100 fold difference, but only 10, is because the code is doing something else, but if you only had locking, you'd notice a greater difference.  Unless the JIT compiler would notice the synchronized block in the loop and hoist it out, but it seems it didn't do it in your test.

Answer (score 0):

If the synchronized block is on `withdraw()` method, only one thread can execute the method at a time, which means when one thread is doing the "fake calculation" other threads must wait. It looks like this:

acquire lock -> fake calc -> modify balance -> fake calc -> release lock

However, if you synchronize only on the one line changing balance in the method, while 1 thread owns the lock, other threads can do the "fake calculation" and it saves some time. It looks like this

fake calc -> acquire lock -> modify balance -> release lock -> fake calc

Notice that in the second way of synchronizing, a thread can acquire the lock right after another thread modifies the balance and releases the lock, so it doesn't have to wait for the fake calculation

Comment: But putting the synchronized block on the withdraw() method is the faster option, that's what I don't understand.

When I just synchronize(this) on the balance calculation, the program takes about a second to run on my system. When I use synchronize(account) on the withdraw() method, the program takes about 0.1 seconds.